# Java I/O method types

Tags: java, methods, input, output

Quick theoretical question:

Why are java Input/Output methods of Integer type?

For example:

```
InputStream
int read()
int read(byte cbuf[])
int read(byte cbuf[], int offset, int length)
```

Comment: To return the number of bytes read.If no data is there and EOF is reached, It returns -1

Comment: The [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) of `java.io.InputStream` describes exactly what the return values of these methods mean.

Answer (score 0):

The first one reads an unsigned byte as an int (since Java's byte is signed you need a bigger data type to hold values from 0-255), the last two methods return the amount of bytes read.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are java Input/Output methods of Integer type?

They aren't. They are of `int` type.

The reason `read()` returns an `int` is so that it can return the out-of-band value -1, meaning end of stream.

The reason the other `read()` methods return `int` is to indicate the number of bytes received, or -1 indicating end of stream.